# Как сделать, чтобы фильтр в Angular включался по checkbox и по нему же отключался?

Tags: angularjs

Хочу, чтобы по кнопке (или checkbox) применялся фильтр orderBy:'-name, при повторном нажатии бы отменялся (типа true-false). Не нашел, как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.useFilter = false;
  
  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'Aaa'},
    {name: 'Zzz'},
    {name: 'Qqq'},
  ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="useFilter"> Use filter</label>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in useFilter ? (items | orderBy : '-name') : items">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересная реализация, спасибо!